# replacing recursive DFS tree traversal with a stack?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, stack

It is well known that one can traverse a tree by DFS (pre-order) using recursion (In Python, for example):

```
def DFS(node):
    if node==None:
       return 0
    valueLeft=DFS(node.left)
    valueRight=DFS(node.right)
    return max(valueLeft,valueRight)+1
```

This code manifestly calculates the height of a tree starting from its root, if we call `DFS(root)`. But there is a problem (...in some machine python has limited recursion stack size and so this code overflows check complains in leetcode...).

Out of curiosity as well as fixing the leetcode problem, how can one transform the above two-branch recursion with value return, into an iterative call using stack? I suppose this is possible since recursion is realized using stack, anyway . I was told so in class from day 1 but have never seen one code so , especially for multi-branch recursion with return values...

i would thank anyone with help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use heap space for the stack - basically maintain your own stack:

```
def dfs2(root):
  stack = [(root,0)]
  depth = 0
  while stack:
    node, d = stack.pop()
    if node == None:
      depth = max(depth,d)
    else:
      stack.push( (node.left, d+1) )
      stack.push( (node.right, d+1) )
  return depth
```

Comment: This is actually wrong right the while is infinite. Since you didn't mark visited nodes

Comment: Can a node have multiple parents? If so it's not a tree. Can you give an example for which the while loop will never terminate?

Comment: @bozeng if this `while` is infinite, so your DFS is also infinite!

Comment: I see so this is never a recursion. In a recursion you need to "go back to the parent " after visiting its children. Then it will push its children back to stack again. Forming a loop. This answer is not recursion. It is just a non recursive version of calculating tree height

Comment: What I want is a true recursive version with stack. If i calculate something else . Or requires in order visit. This thing won't work .

Comment: @bozeng "how can one transform the above two-branch recursion with value return, into an ***iterative*** call using stack?" and now you want a recursive with stack? what do you actually want?

Comment: I want a stack that can realize general recursive functions. That is, after visiting children nodes, the function will return to parent . And won't mistakenly visit its children again .

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/treap/trunk/m4_treap.m4 .  It does a tree traversal without recursion in iterator_macro.

Don't let the file extension fool you - it's m4, but it's m4-preprocessed python so that I can use the same macro for multiple kinds of nonrecursive traversals - specifically iterkeys, itervalues, and iteritems, without a lot of boilerplate in the m4.

Ultimately, the m4 is dispensed with so that the python interpreter only sees python code.

In the same module, reverse_iterator does a nonrecursive traversal too.  If you want to ignore the m4-ness of the others, this might be a simpler place to look.

You can also increase the stack depth of the python interpreter with sys.setrecursionlimit(size), though I think pypy pretty much ignores that.  CPython respects it.